# jsoup Not Catching Full Webpage

Tags: java, html, web, jsoup

Trying to make a super simple bit of code using jsoup to see if a webpage contains a specific word (checks to see the availability of a class to take in-residence).  jsoup seems to be catching lots of the webpage specified, but won't capture all of it - specifically the area I'm interested in.  Is there a reason for this?  Am I doing something wrong?

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String html = Jsoup.connect("https://www.afit.edu/CE/Course_Desc.cfm?p=WENG%20481").maxBodySize(0).get().html();

        System.out.print(html);

        if (html.contains("Resident")) {
            System.out.print("\nAVAILABLE!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's working for me. Which output do you get?

Comment: I seem to be missing almost the entire body of the web page, specifically I'm not getting a return of AVAILABLE! when I should be on this page.  Something on my end?  Here is a text of my output http://freetexthost.com/qsw1jjfd6a

Comment: Maybe something on your end, not sure about that though. You could try copying the user agent from your web browser and using it on JSoup - maybe the webpage changes content with the proper user agent

Comment: It looks like then whole page is there; it shows from <html> to </html>.

Comment: @SteveSmith Yes, but if you compare the output to the one you get by browsing to the site with your browser it's completely different. That's the weird thing.

Comment: @BackSlash Could the extra content be being added dynamically by javascript?  Jsoup will only grab the raw data from the URL.  It won't run any Javascript which your browser will.

Comment: @SteveSmith No. Open your browser, go to that url and check the source code (CTRL+U on most browser). It has all the text

Comment: I noticed the issue by copying my full output from eclipse into a word doc and searching for the text that was displayed on the webpage, which didn't seem to be there in the printout. It seems to only be capturing parts of the page which made me think @SteveSmith might be onto the same thing I was